# Switching pictures in place with ocgx2

Tags: graphics, ocg, ocgx2

Using ocgx2 and pdflatex I would like to switch between two tikzpictures that are identical in size. If I do

```
\switchocg{ocg23a ocg23b}{Lösung}

\begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{1}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[draw=black] (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{ocg}

\begin{ocg}{OCG 2}{ocg2}{0}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[draw=blue] (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

it does switch between the images. However the images being replaced are not at the same position on the page but one above the other.

How can I achieve, that the images are placed at the same position on the page?

Comment: Please make your example complete and compilable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ocg` environment does not prevent its content from taking up space in the output and to push the following content (the second `tikzpicture`) forward. Thus, you have to put the first `tikzpicture` in a zero-width, left aligned LR box.

Also, unprotected line endings and empty lines produce space and paragraphs, respectively, in the output.

The fixed code might look like this (the `ocg` references in the switch command had to be corrected too):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\switchocg{ocg1,ocg2}{Lösung}

\begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{on}
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\begin{tikzpicture} %<== make tikzpicture zero-width
      \draw[draw=black] (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{ocg}%                              <== protected line ending
%                                       <== commented paragraph
\begin{ocg}{OCG 2}{ocg2}{off}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[draw=blue] (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{ocg}
\end{document}
```

Comment: seem it should be `\switchocg{ocg1 ocg2}{Lösung}`?

Comment: With `ocgx2` both, space and comma, can be used as separators. Comma was added to the package as it looks more conform to LaTeX standards.

Comment: Many thanks! And is there any way to make a picture(e.g. by `\includegraphics{...}`) as the sencond arguments of `\switchocg` instead of general text?

Comment: Yes, anything that can be typeset works as button face.

Comment: I tried this: `\switchocg{bla}{\includegraphics{mypicture}}`, the picture was typeset, but when I click it, the matter `bla` point to did not hide/show. Contrary `\switchocg{bla}{button}` works.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Would you mind posting a new question, maybe?

Comment: I just post my question. Would you have a look at it? Thank you. `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601661/how-to-make-a-picture-work-as-switch-in-switchocg-of-the-package-ocgx2`