# How to make a picture work as switch in \switchocg of the package ocgx2

Tags: macros, spacing, page-breaking, text-decorations

I tried to hide something in my article and switch it on/off by the macro `\switchocg` from the package `ocgx2`.

It works all right when the button face is general text. However, when I tried including a picture or drawing a picture as the button, the hidden content fails to switch on/off.

How to deal with this problem? My MWE as below:

PS: I use `xelatex` as compiler, and view the pdf document by `Adobe Acrobat XI`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,ocgx2,graphics}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{1}
  ocg1 ocg1 ocg1 ocg1
\end{ocg}\vskip3em

\begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg2}{1}
   ocg2 ocg2 ocg2 ocg2
\end{ocg}\vskip3em

\begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg3}{1}
   ocg3 ocg3 ocg3 ocg3
\end{ocg}

\switchocg{ocg1}{\fbox{Button}}
\switchocg{ocg2}{\includegraphics{mypicture.png}}
\switchocg{ocg3}{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works for me in different PDF viewers. I even happen to have access to Acrobat-XI, where the example works too as expected. Which TeX distribution are you using, and is it up-to-date? Which `ocgx2` version do you use (look in the `log` file of the `xelatex` run)?

Comment: This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.8.24). `ocgx2 version 0.43`

Comment: Your MiKTeX looks rather old. There has been a major update in the meantime. Now it is MiKTeX-21.6. I don't use MiKTeX myself, but perhaps running the package manager could work already (before you try a complete re-install)?

Comment: I have tried MiKTeX-21.6. It seems not able to work under Windows 7.  So I have to stay in MikTex 2.9. Maybe it's a problem of pdf viewer configuration?

Comment: And is there a way to upload my pdf document constructed by the above code?

Comment: You could open an issue in the `ocgx2` GitLab repo, but you might need to first create an account there: https://gitlab.com/agrahn/ocgx2/-/issues

Comment: Or you put it in a drop box and share the link?

Comment: Would you show me an example ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126601/discussion-between-alexg-and-lyl).